# how to use Mongoose to (add to , update,delete) Nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a fresh mongoose user and I have a small exercise I have this schema

```js
`var BusinessSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    personal_email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    business_name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    business_emails: [{ email: String, Description: String }],  
    business_logo: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
    //Business Services
    services: [{
        service_name: { type:String,required:true},
        service_price: Number,
        promotion_offer : Number,   
        service_rating : [{Clinet_username:String ,rating : Number}],   
        service_reviews : [{Clinet_username:String ,review : String}],  
        type_flag : Boolean,    
        available_flag : Boolean    
    }]
});`
```

what I want to do is to update or add new service or delete rating using mongoose

```js
business.update({// something here to update service_rating },function(err,found_business)
          {
           }); business.update({// something here to add new service_rating },function(err,found_business)
          {
           }); business.update({// something here to delete service_rating },function(err,found_business)
          {
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

`var where_clause = { /* your where clause */ };` 
`var service_rating = {"username", 5};`

to add :

```
business.update(where_clause, {
    '$addToSet' : {
        services.service_rating : service_rating 
    }
}, callback);
```

to delete :

```
business.update(where_clause, { 
    '$pull' : {
        services.service_rating : service_rating
    }
}, callback);
```

to update :

`var other_where = {services.service_rating : {"user", 5}}; // your where clause`

```
business.update(other_where, {
    '$set': {
        'services.service_rating.Clinet_username' : 'newUser', 
        'services.service_rating.rating' : 10
    }
}, callback);
```

Comment: what  will be the where_clause if i want it change the rating of service were  service_name = ser_1 and business_name= bus_1

Comment: `var where_clause = {services.service_name:'ser_1', business_name: 'bus_1'};`

Comment: Your add code looks off. The second argument is not an object.

Comment: @Mikey , didn't notice that, i edited my answer, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: i get this error trying to do the update { MongoError: cannot use the part (services of services.service_reviews) to traverse the element ({services: [ { service_name: "sevice1", service_Description: "test service", service_price: 1000, promotion_offer: 25, _id: ObjectId('58e4c322f0db9f258c33f7fc'), service_reviews: [ { clinet_username: "a", review: "hi", _id: ObjectId('58e4c322f0db9f258c33f7fd') } ], service_rating: [ { clinet_username: "a", rating: 0, _id: ObjectId('58e4c322f0db9f258c33f7fe') } ] } ]})

Comment: I was trying to do the same for the service_reviews array of objects

Comment: i updated my answer for the update part, try `services.service_rating.Clinet_username` instead of `services.$.Clinet_username`